# Complex representation of Clifford Algebra

Tags: linear-transformations, clifford-algebras, representation-of-algebras

In the book Spin Geometry of Lawson was mentioned that a complex representation of $Cl_{r,s}$ is a real representation $\rho:Cl_{r,s}\to\mathrm{Hom}_\mathbb{R}(W,W)$ such that

$\rho\circ J(\phi)=J\circ\rho(\phi)$ for all $\phi\in Cl_{r,s}$.

Note that $J$ is a real linear map from $W$ to itself s.t. $J^2=-\mathrm{Id}$.
I know that I can make a real vector space $W$ with this map to a complex vector space.
My idea was to show that the above relation implies $\rho(\phi)((a+ib)w)=(a+ib)\rho(\phi)(w)$.

Here is one calculation I was trying $(\rho(\phi)\circ J)((a+ib)w)=(\rho(\phi)\circ J)((aw+bJ(w))=\rho(aJ(w)-bw)=a\rho(J(w))-b\rho(w)\overset{!}{=}(J\circ\rho(\phi))((a+ib)w)$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Confused what the issue is. What is the overarching goal here? Why are you trying to verify $\rho(\phi)(i(a+ib)w)=i\rho(\phi)((a+bi)w)$? Just a sanity check? Did you already verify $\rho(\phi)(a+bi)w=(a+bi)\rho(\phi)w$ and $(a+bi)(c+di)={\rm etc}$ is as-expected? What does $\overset{!}{=}$ mean?

Comment: @elemelons Sorry I was seemingly confused.  Is the following correct? $(\rho(\phi))((a+ib)w)=\rho(\phi)(aw+bJ(w)=a\rho(\phi)(w)+b\rho(\phi)(J(w))=a(\rho(\phi))(w)+bJ(\rho(\phi)(w))=(a+bJ)\rho(\phi)(w)=(a+ib)\rho(\phi)(w)$. Do I have to prove anything else?

Comment: What you wrote in your comment is correct. Do you have to prove anything else ... in order to do what? In order to show $\rho$ extends to a complex representation (i.e. a homomorphism into ${\rm End}_{\Bbb C}W$)? No, that should be sufficient.

Comment: Yes in order to show it extends to a complex representation. Thanks a lot